# How to add a button that redirects you to html page django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

In my case, I was creating a template for a PDF that I wanted to be preview-able directly from the admin page where the template was created, so people could see what the result would be of the object they’d just created.
I really just needed a single link with a view that would show a PDF for me, but even something that basic is not immediately obvious in Django admin. I have a `TransactionModel` registered in the `admin` page as below :

```
@ admin.register(Transaction)
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['chp_reference', 'familymember__name']
   inlines = [FamilyGroupInline, FamilyMemberInline]

   def report(self, obj):
       return mark_safe(json2html.convert(json=obj.report, table_attributes="class=\"results\" 
         style=\"overflow-x:auto;\""))

   fieldsets = (
       ('Transaction Details', {
           'fields': ('chp_reference', 'income_period', 'property_market_rent', 
      'rent_effective_date', 'number_of_family_group',),
    }),
    ('Report', {
        'classes': ('collapse',),
        'fields': ('report',),
     }),
   )
    readonly_fields = ['report', 'complete', 'last_rent']
```

i want the `Report` object from the `fieldsets` to be a clickable link that redirect user to a html file, I dont know if that is possible.. and if its, what is the best approach to do so, Thank you!

Here is a traceback for the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\eT3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
    32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "C:\Users\eT3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
    32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, 
    in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in 

inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\eT3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\15-12\cra-calculator-master\project\urls.py", line 45, in <module>
    path('', admin.site.urls),
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 293, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 277, in get_urls
    path('%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
  File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 628, in urls
    return self.get_urls()
  File "E:\15-12\cra-calculator-master\app\admin.py", line 145, in get_urls
    urls += pattern
TypeError: 'URLPattern' object is not iterable
```

here is my `preview_pdf_view()`

```
def preview_pdf_view(self, request, **kwargs):
    tx = Transaction.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
    context = {'tx': tx}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/preview_pdf.html', context=context)
```

`get_url()`

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    pattern = path('preview/<int:id>/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.preview_pdf_view), name='preview-pdf')
    urls += pattern
    return urls
```

and in the `models.py` i added `preview_link()`

```
@property
    def preview_link(self):
        a = '''<a href=" url 'preview-pdf' id={} , name={}"</a>'''.format(self.id, self.chp_reference)
        return mark_safe(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a little custom view in your `TransactionAdmin`:

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def preview_pdf_view(self, request, **kwargs):
        tx = Transaction.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        context = {'tx': tx}
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/preview_pdf.html', context=context)
```

Make sure to create the template `preview_pdf.html`. Here, use the context to render your PDF with `tx.image.url` or however you have that setup.

To make the view accessible, add the url pattern to `TransactionAdmin`'s `get_urls` method:

```
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        pattern = path('preview/<int:id>/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.preview_pdf_view), name='preview-pdf')
        urls += pattern
        return urls
```

Then, you can have a clickable link for each `Transaction` in the admin list view. I would do this at a model level:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

class Transaction(models.Model):

    @property
    def preview_link(self):
        a = '''<a href="{% url 'preview-pdf' id={} %}">{}</a>'''.format(self.id, self.name)
        return mark_safe(a)
```

You can use it in `list_display`, or wherever else as `transaction.preview_link`:

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    list_display = ('preview_link', )
```

See more at Adding Views to Admin Sites https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: thank you for the answer, but im getting an error `TypeError: 'URLPattern' object is not iterable` when adding the `get_url()` function

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the next to last code block that I think is causing that, maybe. See my edit to the ```preview_link``` model method. But also share more of the traceback from your terminal so I can see more about the error.

Comment: I added a traceback to the original post, please check

Comment: hmm, what does your ```get_urls``` method look like? Can you share that? Just want to make sure it looks similar to mine.

Comment: @AbdullaOsama dang my bad on this - in ```get_urls```, set ```pattern``` to a list of url patterns rather than just a url pattern.```patterns = [path('preview/<int:id>/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.preview_pdf_view), name='preview-pdf')]``` THEN it should work. sorry again!

Comment: @AbdullaOsama very glad to help! feel free to mark the answer as accepted when you can :)

Comment: hey thanks again for helping, but im getting an error `page not found` trying to acces the new Url i added, i even cant access it from browser, according to above code i should be able access it when i enter `http://localhost:8000/preview/2/` for example.

Comment: The full URL to access your new view should actually be ```http://localhost:8000/admin/transaction/preview/2/```. When you add patterns by changing your ```get_urls```,  the new pattern will be added to the end of the current model admin URL.